# Unable to attach CSV to a SendGrid email

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sendgrid

Unable to attach a CSV to a email sent through the SendGrid API.

I've tried every iteration of passing the content parameter as base64 encoded regular string and I'm still getting the same error messages.

```py
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Content, Email, Attachment
import numpy as np
import base64

fake_data = np.random.randint(5000, size=(82, 2))
np.savetxt('predictions_test.csv', fake_data, delimiter=",")

message = Mail(
    from_email='FROM_EMAIL',
    to_emails='TO_EMAIL',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>Test Email Body</strong>')


with open('predictions_test.csv', 'rb') as fd:
    b64data = base64.b64encode(fd.read())
    fd.close()


attachment = Attachment()
attachment.content = str(b64data,'utf-8')
attachment.filename = "predictions_test.csv"
attachment.disposition = "attachment"

message.add_attachment(attachment)

try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient('APIKEY')
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e.body))
```

```
Returns the following Error messages is the following: 

b'{"errors":[{"message":"The attachment content is required.","field":"attachments.0.content","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.content"},{"message":"The attachment filename parameter is required.","field":"attachments.0.filename","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.filename"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add as "base64" but we can also add binary data like below

```
with open('predictions_test.csv', 'rb') as fd:
    attachment = Attachment()
    attachment.content = fd.read()
    attachment.filename = "predictions_test.csv"
    attachment.disposition = "attachment"
    message.add_attachment(attachment)
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Still getting the same errors. The content has to be base64 encoded according to that documentation that's linked in the error message.

Comment: The error returned from the API is the following:
b'{"errors":[{"message":"The attachment content is required.","field":"attachments.0.content","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.content"},{"message":"The attachment filename parameter is required.","field":"attachments.0.filename","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments.filename"}]}'